# Why is it said that Laplacians "smooth solutions"?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, smooth-functions

Say you have some PDE for a function $f:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb C$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=Lf,$$

for some differential operator $L$. If $L$ contains a Laplacian term $$\Delta f=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2},$$

why do people claim (as a rule of thumb) that this helps "smooth the solution"? From my understanding they are saying that the solution of the PDE will have better differentiability, but I am unsure why the Laplacian has this effect.

Comment: The concept that helps "smooth solutions" is the notion of elliptic differential operators. The Laplacian is such an operator. For these operators, there is the so-called "elliptic regularity theorem", which says how smooth the solution to the equation must be.

Comment: The expression for the Laplacian should be with second partial derivatives. It's a good question though.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian itself does not smooth the solution. What smooths the solution are the dynamics $${d f\over dt} = |\kappa| \nabla f + \text{other stuff}$$ The intuitive reason is exactly the opposite: the Laplacian *amplifies* regions with large curvature as compared to regions that are relatively flat. The time derivative "pushes" $f$ more in regions where $f$ is rough, and the signs are such that the pushing is towards a smoother $f(x,t)$. If instead  the equation was $${d f\over dt} = -|\kappa| \nabla f + \text{stuff}$$ The Laplacian would cause large curvature regions to get even rougher.